# Outlook add-in on mobile devices

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-app

I am developing an an add-in for Outlook with the Office.js API and I am wondering if it is possible to use it from the `MessageComposeCommandSurface` on Office Online from a mobile device with Android or iOS?

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins It should be possible to run add-ins on the Outlook Web App on iOS devices unless i am misinterpretating it.

I know it is possible to make support the `MobileMessageReadCommandSurface` in the native apps, but our add-in wants to manipulate a message being composed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, we do not support compose add-ins on mobile platforms, whether in the native app or the browser. We track feature requests via UserVoice, and there's currently a feature request for this feature. Please use [this link](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35738695-support-compose-addin-on-mobile) and upvote the feature request. Feature requests on UserVoice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: The fact that it's 8 months later and there's still no apparent progress is not what concerns me. When add-ins were first introduced as "Agaves", the goal was to support the new web-first, cross-platform world. More than seven years later and you still can't build a compose email solution for mobile devices that millions use each day to...compose email. Stop counting votes and fill this stupid hole please

Comment: Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT  any idea of @Eric Legault comment ? . it is still in progress

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the documentation, the gifhy examply sends a gif as a response.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-addin-design

It seems like it bypasses the compose command and sends a message directly. This looks like it might a work around if you can make it fit your use case.